# How long should it take to build an index using ALTER TABLE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

This might be a bit like asking how long a length of string is, but the stats are:

- Intel dual core 4GB RAM
- Table with 8million rows, ~ 20 columns, mostly varchars with an auto_increment primary id
- Query is: ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX `my_index` (my_column);
- my_column is varchar(200)
- Storage is MyISAM

Order of magnitude, should it be 1 minute, 10 minutes, 100 minutes?

Thanks

**Edit:** OK it took 2 hours 37 minutes, compared to 0 hours 33 mins on a lesser spec machine, with essentially identical set ups. I've no idea why it took so much longer. The only possibility is that the prod machine HD is 85% full, with 100GB free. Should be enough, but i guess it depends on how that free space is distributed.

Comment: How long does it take in a test environment?  Server load would be the only thing you couldn't account for, but I couldn't see it taking more than a minute.

Comment: am just running in a dev envirn now. I had expected around 5 mins. 30 minutes later nothing done yet. Additionally in top, mysqld appears very inactive, whilst in dev i'm seeing 60% + of cpu

Comment: Check if you've run out of disk space, in particular in the mysql temp directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are just adding the single index, it should take about 10 minutes. However, it will take 100 minutes or more if you don't have that index file in memory.

Your 200 varchar with 8 million rows will take a maximum of 1.6GB, but with all of the indexing overhead it will take about 2-3 GB. But it will take less if most of the rows are less than 200 characters.  (You might want to do a select `sum(length(my_column))` to see how much space is required.)

You want to edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. Play with these settings;

```
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 100M
sort_buffer_size = 100M
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I did this before with ~4mm rows and it completed pretty rapidly, so yes with 8mm maybe i've probably pushed the index onto disk.

Answer (score 2):

On my test `MusicBrainz` database, table `track` builds a `PRIMARY KEY` and three secondary indexes in `25` minutes:

```
CREATE TABLE `track` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `artist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `length` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modpending` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `gid` (`gid`),
  KEY `artist` (`artist`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The table has `9001870` records.

Machine is `Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6400  @ 2.13GHz` with `2Gb RAM`, `Fedora Core 12`, `MySQL 5.1.42`.

`@@myisam_sort_buffer_size` is `256M`.

Comment: hmm, I don't appear to have myisam_sort_buffer_size or sort_buffer_size specified in my my.cnf...

Comment: ok, so it's completed in my test environment, which has a lower spec (3gb, slighter slower cpu) in 33 minutes. Prod is still churning. i wish there was a status update or something....

Comment: @Richard: if it's not specified, then it has the default value (`8M`). You can check it by issuing `SELECT @@myisam_sort_buffer_size`. This value is way too low, you should increase it (especially if you have `3 Gb` of `RAM`). This memory is only used (and allocated) when creating or repairing the indexes, so it's fine to increase it. `@@sort_buffer_size` does not affect index creation speed, it only affects queries.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you ever need to build multiple indexes, its best to create all indexes in one call instead of individually... Reason: it basically apears to rewrite all the index pages to be inclusive of your new index with whatever else it had.  I found this out in the past having a 2+ gig table and needed to build about 15 indexes on it.  Building all individually kept incrementally growing in time between every index.  Then trying all at once was a little more than about 3 individual indexes since it built all per record and wrote all at once instead of having to keep rebuilding pages.