# Mysql query, three tables left join with group by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, left-join

I have query which provide wrong result, am I doing any thig wrong in this query

```
SELECT   b.nBoutiqueID                       ,
         b.sBoutiqueName                     ,
         b.Status                            ,
         SUM(bs.nViewCount)      nViewCount       ,
         SUM(ps.nViewCount)      nProductViewCount,
         SUM(ps.nLinkClickCount) nLinkClickCount  ,
         SUM(ps.nWishListCount)  nWishListCount   ,
         SUM(ps.nReferredCount)  nReferredCount
FROM     boutique b
         LEFT JOIN boutique_stats bs
         ON       b.nBoutiqueID=bs.nBoutiqueID
         LEFT JOIN product_stats ps
         ON       ps.nBoutiqueID=b.nBoutiqueID
WHERE    b.bDeleted             =0
GROUP BY b.nBoutiqueID
ORDER BY ps.nProductID DESC
```

Query giving not any error, but producing wrong result. I'm Using Mysql.

For particular Instance for  nBoutiqueID=1 the max sum of nViewCount should be 455, but it gives 95124. that is huge difference. any one know why?

Comment: Hmm...i would have thought that having b.sBoutiqueName, b.Status in the SELECT itself should have been a syntax error considering the GROUP clause is only consisting of nBoutiqueID

Comment: It would help if you add the result you expect. The statement itself is ok - depending what you want to do.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the statement executes as well if it's only grouped by nBoutiqueID, yet we have two columns that aren't grouped by or summary functions.. Can somebody in the know explain this?

Comment: @Azz and @In Sane - MySQL does allow this. If the non grouped by columns aren't functionally dependant (i.e. in a 1 to 1 relationship) with the grouped columns you get indeterminate results for these though.

Comment: @In Sane, @Azz : for the recent versions of MySQL you don't need to put everything in the GROUP BY. MySQL will infer it for you.

Comment: @Naresh : can you give an example of content in the table as well as the expected result and the result you are actually receiving ? This would help to see what the problem is, given that the query in syntactically correct.

Comment: As others say, give a small example data set, give the results of the query, and explain what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you are getting a sort-of Cartesian product of the query... Try getting your SUM() values from your sub-queries...

```
SELECT
      b.nBoutiqueID, 
      b.sBoutiqueName, 
      b.Status, 
      bs.StatsViewCount,
      ps.ProductViewCount, 
      ps.ProductLinkClickCount, 
      ps.ProductWishListCount, 
      ps.ProductReferredCount 
   FROM     
      boutique b 
         LEFT JOIN ( select nBoutiqueID, sum( nViewCount ) as StatsViewCount
                        from boutique_stats 
                        group by nBoutiqueID ) bs 
            ON b.nBoutiqueID = bs.nBoutiqueID 
         LEFT JOIN ( select SUM(nViewCount) ProductViewCount, 
                             SUM(nLinkClickCount) ProductLinkClickCount, 
                             SUM(nWishListCount) ProductWishListCount, 
                             SUM(nReferredCount)  ProductReferredCount 
                        from product_stats 
                        group by nBoutiqueID ) ps 
            ON ps.nBoutiqueID=b.nBoutiqueID 
   WHERE    
      b.bDeleted = 0 
   ORDER BY 
      ps.nProductID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Drapp, That query is awesome. I see that type of query first time. Can you pass any link so that i can go more with sub-query in Joins? Any ways thanks.

Comment: No direct links, just personal experience as with all the others out here offering solutions.  However, I've found a few from my historical posts to offer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771179 shows a way of doing a cross-tab from rows to columns  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312608 for query optimizing technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267791 for index timing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352882 for non-standard ordering clause... can also be used as selecting value as columns,..  Just keep an eye out for others looking for answers and those that are offered.

Answer (score 1):

You say "max nViewCount should be 455, but it gives 95124".

But in your query you have `SUM(bs.nViewCount)      nViewCount,`.

Shouldn't that be `MAX(bs.nViewCount)      nViewCount,` ?